# How to selectively bring up helm resources

Tags: resources, kubernetes-helm

I have different multiple StatefulSet resources present in the templates/ directory. Is there a way, they can be selectively brought up?

For example: If I have statefulSet kind resource defined in a.yaml in the templates/ and I only want this to be brought up in a testing environment, not production. Is that possible using some tags/conditions/values.yaml?

Comment: Can someone help with this?

Comment: Any luck here? I have the same problem. For my local, I don't want ingress.yml to be deployed, but I want the same to be deployed for my prod/qa env.